# Does child class call overiding method when calling indirectly through parent?

Tags: java

If method in class A calls parent method in Class B which calls method X in class B which is overridden in class A, which implementation of method X will be called? The overridden implementation in child class A or the original implementation in parent class B?

From my code, I see that the override method is called, but I imagined that if a method was called from a class, the method would not be the overriding method in a subclass. I guess if a subclass calls a method in the parent which calls a method which is overridden in the subclass, the overridden method will be called? Is that right? Why?

Comment: You’ve answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Think about abstract methods in parent class, which may be called by other non abstract methods of that parent (yes, it compiles!)

It's always a virtual method call, always the child's implementation (except for static methods and private ones of course).

It's on purpose that the parent can call child's overridden method.

Comment: You are saying the parent method calls the override always?

Comment: Doesn't make sense if more than one class can share the same parent; which implementation would the parent call in that case?

Comment: It isn't "the parent class" making the call though, it's the object itself that is.  Meaning an individual object only has one parent, so it's always going to call its own methods first, then work its way up the virtual method chain to call the first method it finds.  Note if you don't want this behavior, you make a method private or final, which prevents subclasses from overriding and changing that particular method.

Answer (score 0):

For non-static methods, the JRE looks for overrides and calls the child method, even if the caller is a method in the parent.

Static methods are do not override.